# How do I get iPads to upload images?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, ipad

Okay, so as it turns out a very simple browse button does absolutely nothing for iPads, I don't know if this stays true for macs in general but from what I can gather around stack exchange and google is that there's a policy restricting image upload (If I understand correctly).

I have provided a piece of code which also changes the appearance of the browse button using Javascript. But of course, that's not necessary at all because the default browse html button doesn't work anyway.

I usually solve my own problems but I know next to nothing about anything mac-related and so I don't really know what to search for. I'm hoping someone out there could explain to me how to add compatibility or at least guide me to the right direction. Thank you!

Oh, and it's iOS7.

For anyone who's interested, here's the code that doesn't work on ipad:
http://pastebin.com/hWPh4dRK

Comment: So... what's the question? If you're actually asking how to upload images on an iPad, that's off-topic for SO. Are you asking why your existing code doesn't work on an iPad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not able to access pastebin for some weird reason, but did you try

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

Source : http://www.webmonkey.com/2012/09/new-html-tricks-for-web-developers-in-apples-ios-6-2/

demo : https://longhandpixels.net/demos/mobilesafari-ios6/

Comment: Kudos! That's exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know that there was a such thing as capture. I read a little bit already into it and will read more after I post this but yes, it does resolve the problem. Thank you! I'd vote you up but I don't have the karma yet.